# How to get a variable's name based on its value

Tags: r

If I have a list of interger, and I gave them string names, how do i get the name based on the value?

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would make your question more precise and easier to verify potential answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x <- list(a=2L,b=3L) 
names(x[which(x==2)])
```

Comment: Or, logically, just `names(x[x == 2])`

Answer (score 1):

`match` with `names` works:

```
x <- list(a=2L,b=3L)

names(x)[match(2L,x)]
# [1] "a"
```

This also works if `x` is not actually a `list`, but a vector: `x <- c(a=2L,b=3L)`.

If the value is not unique, it selects the first match:

```
x <- list(a=2L,b=3L,d=2L)
names(x)[match(2L,x)] # still "a"
```